# Git, different folders, same repo, different branches

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

Thanks for reading this question. I have a task to do, and I'm shame of it, but I can not handle it myself. That's why I'm here, to ask you give me a hand with it. So, the problem is...I have the following site structure:

> ext_www
>   -- dev
>   ----(site code here)
>   www
>   --(site code here)

**ext_www/dev** folder is the place where **dve** branch wanted to be located. And the **www** is the folder where **master** branch wanted to be located. So I want to build a file structure like this:

> .git
>   ext_www
>   -- dev(*dev branch*)
>   ----(site code here)
>   www(*master branch*)
>   --(site code here)

Is it possible to set .git folder in one place, then set the **master** branch go into the **www** folder and the **dev** branch go into the **ext_www/dev** folder, and at the same time to keep in the repo a pure site source code with no **www** or **ext_www/dev** folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use git [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules):

1 - Add the first submodule:

```
git submodule add https://github.com/link-to/your-repo.git ext_www
```

2 - Checkout to `dev`branch:

```
cd ext_www && git checkout dev
```

3 - Add another submodule:

```
cd ../ && git submodule add https://github.com/link-to/your-repo.git www
```

4 - Checkout to `master` branch:

```
cd www/ && git checkout master
```

5 - [optional] Return to your root directory and commit all these changes.

Comment: Thank you so much. This works for me. The issue solved